# Thymeleaf, dont insert linebreaks in numbers

Tags: java, thymeleaf, whitespace

I have following line in thymeleaf

```
<td th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(p.position, 0, 'WHITESPACE', 4, 'POINT')}">POSITION</td>
```

So using whitespace as separator in looong numbers, for readability.
This works otherwise but now i have linebreaks in middle of numbers in tables, making even more hard to read than it was before.
like this:

```
160
120.3292
```

Is there way to use "`&nbsp;`" type of character or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css to prevent line breaks. (`white-space: nowrap` should work for this.)

```
<td th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(p.position, 0, 'WHITESPACE', 4, 'POINT')}" style="white-space: nowrap;">POSITION</td>
```